# Inserción de datos de dataframe (Python) a postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe

Estoy intentando meter datos desde un dataFrame a postgres.
Tengo todos los datos cargados en eldataframe, pero al insertarlo en postgres me da problemas de formato.

Tengo la tabla creada así:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DL.desempleo (id varchar(2) NOT NULL, Periodo VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL, Total DECIMAL);
```

Y la inserción así:

```
INSERT INTO DL.desempleo (id,Periodo, Total) values (%s,%s,%d)
```

Alguien me puede decir con que formato meto el valor Total que es Decimal (7.55), si lo pongo como %d me da el siguiente error:

```
Error al conectar con PostgreSQL unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index %Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes reemplazar el `%d` por `%s`, en las preguntas y respuestas sobre el uso de `psycopg` está comentado: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions

> I can’t pass an integer or a float parameter to my query: it says a number is required, but it is a number!
> In your query string, you always have to use %s placeholders, even when passing a number. All Python objects are converted by Psycopg in their SQL representation, so they get passed to the query as strings. See Passing parameters to SQL queries.

```
>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%d)", (42,)) # WRONG
>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%s)", (42,)) # correct
```

Comment: lo he probadocon %s pero me dice esto:     Error al conectar con PostgreSQL la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo numeric: «..»
LINE 1: ...NTO DL.desempleo (id,Periodo, Total) values ('18',2020,'..')

Comment: Está viniendo `..` en el último valor `('18',2020,'..')`, verifica que esté asignando el valor correcto, evidentemente ese no es una entrada válida para numeric

Comment: Es una buena respuesta y correcta. Sin embargo, podrías editar la respuesta y citar la sección de las preguntas y respuestas donde aclaran eso por favor? Si en un futuro el link se cae, tu respuesta se volverá inútil para futuros lectores.

Comment: Gracias, actualizada la respuesta

Comment: Tienes razón @Antony Sotolongo, he tenido que limpiar los datos y quitar lo de los dos puntos. Un saludo y gracias